# Enable text zoom via Ctrl+Wheel in QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qplaintextedit

The documentation mentions that <kbd>Ctrl+Wheel</kbd> key binding for zooming in/out is supported for QPlainTextEdit in both the [editing key bindings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#editing-key-bindings) and the [read-only key bindings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#read-only-key-bindings) entries.

This made me assume that this feature is there out of the box. However, when I do <kbd>Ctrl+Wheel</kbd>, nothing happens. Is there something in particular that I need to do to turn on that feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it yourself. I wrote code snippet which can zoom in or out when you press `Ctrl` and use wheel

In my case, I use `eventFilter`

```
if(obj == ui->plainTextEdit && event->type() == QEvent::Wheel )
{
    QWheelEvent *wheel = static_cast<QWheelEvent*>(event);
    if( wheel->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier )
        if(wheel->delta() > 0)
            ui->plainTextEdit->zoomIn(2);
        else
            ui->plainTextEdit->zoomOut(2);
}
```

Or simply make your `textEdit` `readOnly`

```
ui->plainTextEdit->setReadOnly(true);
```

Now you have choice: zooming with blocked `QPlainTextEdit` or zooming when user wants it(without blocking).

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't work if you set font size through stylesheets.